# MYSQL Join tables create new columns

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to join tables; the first being a fixture which contains the teams playing with their abbreviated names, and the second table which contains all the teams details, such as full names & home venues.

I would like to join these tables and display the full names of the 2 x teams playing and the venue of the home team.

My code below shows everything i need except i need the away team full name which i need to be displayed.

```
SELECT f.mid
     , f.gid
     , f.hteam
     , f.ateam
     , p.venue
     , p.fname as hteam
     , p.fname as ateam
  FROM fixtures f
  JOIN teams p 
    ON p.abbrev = f.hteam
WHERE mid = 1
```

Table 1 (fixtures)

```
mid gid  hteam ateam
1    1   WCE   LIV
1    2   MUN   ESS
```

Table 2 (teams)

```
fname       abbrev  venue
WEST COAST   WCE    OPTUS
LIVERPOOL    LIV    ANFIELD
MANCHESTER   MUN    OLD TRAFFORD
ESSENDON     ESS    WINDY HILL
```

Answer (score 1):

You must join `fixtures` to 2 copies of `teams`:

```
SELECT f.mid, f.gid, f.hteam, f.ateam, 
       t1.venue, t1.fname hteam, t2.fname ateam
FROM fixtures f
JOIN teams t1 ON t1.abbrev = f.hteam
JOIN teams t2 ON t2.abbrev = f.ateam
WHERE f.mid = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a join to `teams`, because you need info on two teams:

```
SELECT 
   f.mid, 
   f.gid, 
   f.hteam, 
   f.ateam, 
   p.venue, 
   p.fname as hteam,
   a.fname as ateam
FROM fixtures f
JOIN teams p ON p.abbrev = f.hteam
JOIN teams a On a.abbrev = f.ateam
WHERE mid = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get a full name for the away team by using a subquery in `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT f.mid, f.gid, f.hteam, f.ateam, p.venue, p.fname as hteam,
       (SELECT fname FROM teams WHERE abbrev = f.ateam) as ateam
FROM fixtures f
JOIN teams p ON p.abbrev = f.hteam
WHERE mid = 1
```

[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d91cb/1)

Comment: Well, it's not what I'd do :-(

Comment: A reason or explaination would help all of us learn from your experience.

Comment: I tend to avoid sub queries except where necessary (or where they demonstrably improve performance)

Comment: Thank you and I agree, but when table size grows, splitting the queries has helped me in real-life situations.